# DateTimeFormat with ISO parameter not parsing timezone correctly

Tags: java, spring, datetime, datetime-format

I have this controller which I'm trying to test using mockMVC

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something/{language}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json", "application/xml" })
    public ResponseEntity<someEntity> getInfo( 
            @PathVariable String language, 
            @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) @RequestParam(required = false) Date fromDate
    )
```

So I'm expecting to allow date formats like in docs to be parsable:
DATE_TIME
The most common ISO DateTime Format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ, e.g.

However I keep on getting things like this:

Handler execution resulted in exception: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: 
Failed to conv ert from type java.lang.String to type 
@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat 
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam java.util.Date for value '2015-09-26T01:30:00.000Z'; nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to parse '2015-09-26T01:30:00.000Z'
```

As far as I can see I'm not doing anything wrong, which must be of course.
Can anyone shine a light what my bad is? I don't think I need to post more code since the exception does show the correct value which I'm passing to the API right?

Comment: i believe problem is with last char `Z` as it represents zone in date time parsing patterns

Comment: Well normally this works fine, and when I serialize in this format is also works fine.

Right now I'm just accepting a string and converting that to a date manually.

It might have to do with the fact that it is a GET request

Comment: your date time string is incorrect as per ISO.DATE_TIME Format it should be `2015-09-26T01:30:00.000<actual timezone value>` instead of `2015-09-26T01:30:00.000Z` for ex. `2015-09-26T01:30:00.000-04:00`

Comment: Z is in fact a timezone (UTC). The ISO spec states that if the string ends with 'Z' means the UTC timezone. This is a bug. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)

Answer (score 9):

### How it works

You receive the Date as an `String` (HTTP Request is text based) and instruct Spring on how to convert it to an Date Object by a `pattern`.

```
//Spring controller 
@GetMapping
public List<Foobar> find(
   @RequestParam(name = "startDate", required = false)
   @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "YOUR_DATE_PATTERN" or iso="ISO Enum member") //how to convert the date string
   Date startDate {
  return service.find(startDate); //work with the java.util.Date object
}
```

Spring will delegate this task to the `java.text.DateTimeFormat`, so the pattern **should be a valid one for the formatter class to work with.**

#### @DateTimeFormat - Pattern VS Iso

- Pattern : Specify your pattern. Will be passed directly to the formatter.
- Iso : An member of `org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat.ISO`Enum, that has a pre-built Date String Pattern. From the Enum docs:

> DATE The most common ISO Date Format yyyy-MM-dd, e.g.
>
> DATE_TIME The most common ISO DateTime Format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ, e.g.
>
> NONE Indicates that no ISO-based format pattern should be applied.
>
> TIME The most common ISO Time Format HH:mm:ss.SSSZ, e.g.

- **Notice that ALL Enum members (except for NONE), uses 'Z' for the timezone.**

#### What 'Z' means in the date pattern?

- Looking at the Javadocs of the Date and Time Patterns, we have two options to handle timezones:

  1. 'Z' Char : RFC 822 Timezone Syntax **(Spring will use this syntax)**

> ```
> zone      =  "UT"  / "GMT"                ; Universal Time
>                                         ; North American : UT
>
>         /  "EST" / "EDT"                ;  Eastern:  - 5/ - 4
>
>         /  "CST" / "CDT"                ;  Central:  - 6/ - 5
>
>         /  "MST" / "MDT"                ;  Mountain: - 7/ - 6
>
>         /  "PST" / "PDT"                ;  Pacific:  - 8/ - 7
>
>         /  1ALPHA                       ; Military: Z = UT;
>                                         ;  A:-1; (J not used)
>                                         ;  M:-12; N:+1; Y:+12
>
>         / ( ("+" / "-") 4DIGIT )        ; Local differential
>                                         ;  hours+min. (HHMM)
> ```

2. 'X' Char : ISO 8601 Timezone designators

> Time offsets (15:00−03:30) OR 'Z' for UTC/GMT timezone

#### The issue

- If you select `org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME` Enum member, it will use the `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` pattern with the RFC 822 syntax for the timezones.

#### The fix

- Use the same pattern but with the 'X' for the timezones (use the ISO 8601 syntax) :

  `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`

#### About the Z Timezone

- ISO 8601 states:

> Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)
>
> If the time is in UTC, add a Z
>   directly after the time without a space. Z is the zone designator for
>   the zero UTC offset. "09:30 UTC" is therefore represented as "09:30Z"
>   or "0930Z". "14:45:15 UTC" would be "14:45:15Z" or "144515Z".
>
> The Z suffix in the ISO 8601 time representation is sometimes referred
>   to as "Zulu time" because the same letter is used to designate the
>   Zulu time zone. However the ACP 121 standard that defines the list of
>   military time zones makes no mention of UTC and derives the "Zulu
>   time" from the Greenwich Mean Time[27] which was formerly used as the
>   international civil time standard.

#### Related Links

- [Spring - Javadocs - DateTimeFormat Annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html)
- [Spring - Javadocs - DateTimeFormat.ISO Enum](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html)
- [Java - Javadocs - Date and Time Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
- [RFC 822 - Standard for ARPA Internet Text Messages -  Date and Time Specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/#z28)
- [ISO 8601 - Timezone Designators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators)

Comment: Got  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: X when using yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX for datetimeformat. version 5.1.3 DateTimeFormat.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your issue?

Comment: Sure. Got java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: X when mapping the request parameter to controller method with `doSomething(@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")` for input 2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z

Comment: Also the enum java docs second link changed from Z to X. So longer using Z for time zone.

Answer (score 3):

As per `DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME`

> The most common ISO DateTime Format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ, e.g.
>   2000-10-31 01:30:00.000-05:00.

Where a `Z` represents a timezone value for example -05:00.

Your string value which is unparseable is `2015-09-26T01:30:00.000Z` where Z must be replaced with actual timezone value.

For example `2015-09-26T01:30:00.000-04:00` will be parsed by `ISO.DATE_TIME` correctly

Comment: While it is true that "2015-09-26T01:30:00.000-04:00" is valid and can be parsed, "2015-09-26T01:30:00.000Z" is also a valid ISO 8601 String with Z standing for UTC ("Zulu"). See top answer

Answer (score 1):

Try **not** to pass the parameter `fromDate` as a String.

I had the same issue and when I unwrapped the parameter's value from double quotes (`"`) in the API call (I used Postman), it worked. You might have to encode some of the characters (i.e. +) though.